# SwiftUI interface orientation specific layouts

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have started experimenting with SwiftUI in order to port my app from UIKit to SwiftUI. Below is the code that is one of the building blocks. Basically, I want to place a 16:9 red subview in the center of the screen if current interface orientation is `.landscape` with a small offset to the left(offset dependent on `safeAreaInsets`). If the orientation is `.portrait`, then the red subview has aspect ratio 9:16 and is placed in the center with a small vertical offset (determined by `safeAreaInsets`). I have used `device.orientation` in the below code but I am looking for a better solution for a reason. Reason being that in UIKit, I could programatically turn on/off autorotation or fix orientation of view controller to a configured choice. I did not therefore rely on `UIDevice orientation` in UIKit. It doesn't seems to be straightforward in SwiftUI. I would not want to rely on device orientation therefore.

```
  var body: some View {
    Color.black
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay(alignment: .center,  content: {
            Color.red
                .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .offset(x:previewHorizontalOffset, y:previewVerticalOffset)
            
        })
        .persistentSystemOverlays(.hidden)   
    }

   var aspectRatio:CGFloat {
       if !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
          return 9.0/16.0
       } else {
          return 16.0/9.0
       }
   }

    var previewHorizontalOffset:CGFloat {
        if !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
           return 0
        } else {
           return -15
        }
    }

    var previewVerticalOffset:CGFloat {
       if !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
          return 15
       } else {
          return 0
       }
    }
```

Comment: You may consider the size (or the ration) of the view instead of the orientation of the device, since some devices (like iPad and Mac) has multiple sizes per orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GeometryReader` to read the size of the `View` and decide whether or not it's `landscape` based on that size:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let isLandscape: Bool = proxy.size.width > proxy.size.height
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay(alignment: .center,  content: {
                    Color.red
                        .aspectRatio(aspectRatio(isLandscape: isLandscape), contentMode: .fit)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .offset(x:previewHorizontalOffset(isLandscape: isLandscape),
                                y:previewVerticalOffset(isLandscape: isLandscape))
                    
                })
                .persistentSystemOverlays(.hidden)
        }
    }
    
    func aspectRatio(isLandscape: Bool) -> CGFloat {
        if !isLandscape {
            return 9.0/16.0
        } else {
            return 16.0/9.0
        }
    }
    
    func previewHorizontalOffset(isLandscape: Bool) -> CGFloat {
        if !isLandscape {
            return 0
        } else {
            return -15
        }
    }
    
    func previewVerticalOffset(isLandscape: Bool) -> CGFloat {
        if !isLandscape {
            return 15
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `GeometryReader` greedily takes up space. If this affects your layout in unintended ways, you may want to use something like this: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/

Comment: While `GeometryReader` has unintended side effects, the link you shared is interesting and useful.

Comment: @DeepakSharma did this answer your question? Given the code you've provided, it seems to solve the issue

Comment: I resorted to another trick as of now to detect `interfaceOrientation` by testing `verticalSizeClass == .regular`. Though this test will fail for iPad, but as of now it solves my purpose. Using GeometryReader has unintended side effects. I tried solutions in the link but they caused lot of alignment problems.